# SuperCapacitor Charger with BQ25173

Tags: circuit-design, supercapacitor

I am asking about supercapacitor charger with BQ25173 IC. I examined the datasheet and designed my circuit for about 13 mA, but when I built the circuit, the current that was needed to charge the capacity was at microampere levels. I set up ISET pin for 13mA but it did not happen. What would be the reason? I need your suggestion.
BQ25173 and supercapacitor datasheet in below !
My calculation and real life application result are different.

[BQ25173 IC](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ25173)

[SuperCapacitor 3S 15F 4.2V](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28409/196hvc.pdf)

[image: my application]

Comment: What is your input voltage?  Your ISET resistor of 600 ohms gives a 500 mA charge current, not 13 mA.  Your feedback divider gives a charge termination regulation voltage of 8.8 V which is enough to damage the capacitor.  If the circuit you posted isn't what you are using please post your exact circuit with component values and input voltage range.

Comment: Vin=5V, this picture is an application in datasheet, my ISET resistor is, about 22K, and FB resistors are proportional to 4.25.  in datasheet formula says; VReg=Vfb_ref * (Rfbt+Rfbb) / Rfbb so, Vreg is my supercapacitor voltage, Vfb_ref is 0.8 datasheet says that and Rfbt and Rfbb voltage divider resistor. When I do the calculation according to the datasheet, I actually get very different values.

Comment: Other than the value of your ISET resistor, I have no idea what your last comment meant.  What are your values for your feedback resistor? What "different" values do you get when you do the calculations? Again, it would be helpful to see your full schematic, including component values and whatever decoupling capacitors you have, etc.

Comment: Hi John, I edited the schematic, waiting for your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: my Vout target is 3.8V, and according the datasheet CE floating IC is active. (but I can change as low) FB resistors are 232k and 56k

Comment: (470 kΩ+ *100* kΩ yields slightly above 3.8 V.) When measuring current, is a discharged capacitor or a resistor < 3.8 V / 11 mA connected to the output?

Comment: Hi Greybeard, now I try to discharge, I de-energized the circuit and I am discharging 1w load. and capacity output current is fixed 1.5uA

Comment: Your schematic looks OK.  As @greybeard said you should test with a discharged capacitor on the output (which is what I think you said you're doing).  It would be helpful to know what the PG and STAT pins are doing, but you don't have the required pull-up on STAT.  You could wire a pull-up to STAT to see if it gives any clues.  Your layout could also be an issue so if you want to post that we can take a look at it.

Comment: Hello, I changed the capacitor, this time the theoretical value and the measured value are the same. But after 20 minutes the capacitance current dropped a lot and the voltage value did not rise. (Cap. " https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-beyschlag-draloric-bc-components/MAL223531016E3/12813159 ") charging voltage is 0.775V but not higher.